# Using .replace() function on Scrapy parsed data not working as expected

Tags: python, scrapy

Before I start, apologies that this is my third attempt at getting across what my issue is. The last two questions seem to have suffered communication breakdown. I am using the following Scrapy code:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.item import Item
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy import log
from scrapy.cmdline import execute
from scrapy.utils.markup import remove_tags
import time
import re
import json


class ExampleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "mrcrawl2"
    allowed_domains = ["whoscored.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.whoscored.com"]
    download_delay = 5

    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/Seasons'),deny=('/News', '/Fixtures', '/Graphics', '/Articles', '/Live', '/Matches', '/Explanations', '/Glossary', '/Players', 'ContactUs', 'TermsOfUse', 'Jobs', 'AboutUs', 'RSS'),), follow=False, callback='parse_item')]

    def parse_item(self, response):

        sel = Selector(response)

        regex = re.compile('DataStore\.prime\(\'history\', { stageId: \d+ },\[\[.*?\]\]?\)?;', re.S) #use regex to find none html data on page

        match2g = re.search(regex, response.body)

        if match2g is not None:
            match3g = match2g.group()

            match3g = str(match3g)
            match3g = match3g.replace("'", '').replace("'", '').replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace('] );', '') #replace some characters from returned string

            match3g = re.sub("DataStore\.prime\(history, { stageId: \d+ },", '', match3g) #here replacing also
            match3g = match3g.replace(');', '') #and here

            new_match3g = '' #create empty variable
            for line in match3g.split("\n"): #for each line of old string
                upl = line.rsplit(",",1)[1:] #split at the last comma
                if upl:
                    upl1 = "{}".format("".join(list(upl[0]))) #new data format
                    upl2 = "{}".format(",".join(list(upl[0]))) #old data format
                    upl2 = str(upl2) #convert both to strings
                    upl1 = str(upl1)
                    new_match3g += line.replace(upl1, upl2) + '\n' #replace old substring with new one in new string created from old

                    print "UPL1 = ", upl1 #print new and old substrings to confirm conversion completed correctly
                    print "UPL2 = ", upl2

            print new_match3g.decode('utf-8') #print new and old strings to confirm the new string has been built correctly
            print match3g.decode('utf-8')



execute(['scrapy','crawl','mrcrawl2'])
```

The purpose of this is to take all digits after the last comma in each line of data parsed and separate these bites out using commas.

An example of the conversion taking place would be:

`,000` to `,0,0,0,`

Once this process is completed, I am then creating a new empty variable 'new_match3g' and filling this, line by line with the old variable 'match3g', only with my new, comma separated string replacing the old, non comma separating one.

I am then printing both the old and new string as well as the before and after transformation substrings to observe whether this is working correctly.

For most examples it does, however seemingly at random, certain substrings generated are not added to 'new_match3g' correctly, even though they have been converted correctly in the variable 'upl2'.

If you were to run this code through yourself and observe some of the output you would see what I mean. What I don't understand is why this is only happening on certain lines, seemingly at random.

Thanks

Comment: ah ok, so when you split save the rest of your string that will not be modified in a variable, and just concat it to your updated string

Comment: @PadraicCunningham what i dont understand though is that im splitting the string in three places (first two not included here for simplicity/clarity). the process works 100% for them. for the third .replace() statement i am using (the one in the code above) it works most of the time, but randomly not at other times. can you explain why this is at all? thanks

Comment: forget about replace just rejoin

Comment: @PadraicCunningham ok, i will have a look at that tomorrow and see if it does the trick. thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I will add an example, you  will have to tweak but I think joining and having separate variables will be easier to follow

Answer (score 1):

```
s = "foo,bar,foo,foobar"
spl = s.rsplit(",",1) 
to_be_updated = spl[1:] 
updated = ",".join(to_be_updated[0])
orig = spl[0:1]
final = orig[0] +","+ updated
foo,bar,foo,f,o,o,b,a,r
```